# How can I get access to the request url from a ServiceStack.Razor layout template?

Tags: razor, servicestack

I have defined a layout template .cshtml for my site using the following method:
`@{ Layout = "InsideLayout"; }`

I am now trying to grab the request url to figure out what navigation menu item should be marked as active at any point in time.  It however looks like the Request object is null (however unable to get a break point in the view, so not 100% that's the issue, but pretty sure).

To me, it seems that the current Request object should be populated properly in a Layout view, so it can some context sensitive markup in it, but as is this doesn't seem possible.  Is there a specific class that the layout must inherit from to enable this, or is what I'm seeing the expected behavior?

Another option I was thinking might work, is to create a custom service to back the layout view.  I tried this, however I wasn't able to get the service code to execute when a page using the layout was loaded.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should have access to the Request inside the view. But a better way to do that is to pass it in the model. Simply add the information as a property to the model that you are passing to this view and have the service populate it.

Comment: There is no backing model for my layout, as i couldn't get any "service" to run for the layout .cshtml like i am able to for a normal (non layout template) view.

Comment: Alright, so you are saying that the `Request` object is null? That's very surprising.

Comment: I think so, i'm not able to get a break point in the view itself, however if i try to use any property of this.Request the rendering throws a HTTP500.  :(

Comment: And can't you get more information about this error 500? Have you looked at the EventLog?

Comment: Strangely no.  Not sure why, but I just get a blank page rendered:   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" 
content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>

Comment: Is there some exception written to the EventLog?

Comment: Actually yes, but it looks like its just at startup time...    Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

Message: Type 'ServiceStack.Razor.Templating.TemplateCompilationException' in Assembly 'ServiceStack.Razor, Version=3.9.33.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22694/discussion-between-jessep-and-darin-dimitrov)

Comment: I'm still not able to get anywhere on this.  It just appears that the Request object isn't available in a Layout (not _Layout.cshtml, but a manually specified layout in each page like:  @{ Layout = "InsideLayout"; }   If there's any way i can get this object to expose properly, and/or tie up a "Service" instance to my "InsideLayout" layout view, i'll be a happy camper.  :)